# Scroll up the page to previous input on terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, scrolling, usability

In the work that I am doing, sometimes the output of a certain command is so large, that it becomes very challenging to find the first few lines of the output. By large I mean so large that scrolling by keys is too slow, and scrolling with the mouse via scrollbar just misses the right line each time because it's too fast.

I want to scroll up the whole "page" of the terminal to where my previous command has been inputted. Note that I am *not* asking how to get the previous commands behind my cursor — I am aware that that can be done by pressing the "up" button.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect the output into a file then edit it with gedit

```
COMMAND > output.txt
```

then

```
gedit output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the long output from start where you enter the command you can use `less` command in pipeline.

eg:

```
ls | less
```

It would be like this

```
'your command' | less
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, to renter it, press up, and then it will fill. You can also edit it, to change it rather than retyping it.

Or you can run `!!` if you don't need to edit it...

This is probably one of the best terminal tricks!

Comment: Just to add, if you don't need to edit your last command, you can also use `!!` to rerun the last command.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I meant to ask. I have made corrections to make myself more clear.